# Does Google stackdriver error report API support gevent?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-stackdriver

I am trying the Error Report API of GCP.

The code hangs and gives 503 Deadline Exceeded error. The code worked if "monkey.patch_all()" was removed. Does the API support gevent?

```py
import gevent
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all()

from google.cloud import error_reporting

client = error_reporting.Client.from_service_account_json(
                'configs/trading-xxxxx.json',service='test2')
print("Start")
client.report('test2313')
print("End")
```

google.api_core.exceptions.ServiceUnavailable: 503 Deadline Exceeded

Answer (score 2):

I have got the answer from Github.
Add the following code:

```
import grpc._cython.cygrpc
grpc._cython.cygrpc.init_grpc_gevent()
```

More details here:
https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/9192

Answer (score 0):

I believe in order to configure Gevent on Stackdriver you will need to declare it in your applications requirements.txt. this article on how to install Gunicorn mentions it [1].

[1] https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/runtime#recommended_gunicorn_configuration

Comment: Thank you. I am testing locally, and plan to deploy it on Google Compute Engine. So I think the document on app engine setup is not relevant. In addition, the dependencies were all in the requirements.txt.